# List of Profiling results sessions of Mini Profiler

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

How to get a list of all profiling sessions from Mini Profiler?

I am using the [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/) for Dot Net Project.

Comment: List of past profiling sessions or sessions that are currently executing?

Comment: I'm looking for past profiling sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**http://localhost:15536/mini-profiler-resources/results-index**

You can use this link & just replace http://localhost:15536 with your domain name & you will get list of session.